# Event sync between iPhone calendar and outlook 2016 calendar results in a time zone error

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, ms-office, calendar

I have a IPhone 6S w/ IOs 10.2 and Outlook 2016 (office 365) in my Menovo ideapad 710S 64 bits with Windows 10.

When I add a new event in ICloud calendar, the event apperas one hour later in the  Outlook calendar, and when I add a new event in Outlook calendar it appears one hour earlier in ICloud Cal.

Both devices are setted in the same time zone. How can I discover or correct this time zone error?

Answer (score 1):

I turned away from iCloud Control Panel for Windows earlier because of some other reason that iCloud folders of contact, calendar and task cannot be used as Outlook default folder. This often gives me a headache that I have to always click into icloud folders before creating new entries. The solution I found working for me is EVO Collaborator for Outlook. Regarding to the time zone issue in the question, I have never met such problem because I think the Outlook add-in self-adjusts to the time zone you are at vs. what is on your iCloud account. You can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I fix this is to sign in to the web interface for the calendar in question. From that interface - be sure you have set the main account to enable time zone support and that the time zone is the one you want. Then - you will have a version of what the "truth" on the server is. Then you can easily tell which OS is messed up and make adjustments.

While you're at it - set a calendar reminder for the day before the next daylight time switch so you know to revisit this. It's often not clear that things are really correct until you see both clients through the fall back and spring forward changes if any.